# I am trying to use the TextInputLayout for my register screen however it does not show any hints that I have in the Edit text

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

The button that is also included here does not show up along with a check box for terms and conditions and all other UI elements. Does it have to do anything with the Text Input Layout or something else?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.RegisterActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_register_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.example.pcwares.utils.pcwarestextviewbold
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/toolbar_title_paddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:text="@string/create_account"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/toolbar_title_text_size" />


</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_register_activity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_first_name"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_first_name"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

            <com.example.pcwares.utils.pcwaresedittext
                android:id="@+id/et_first_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="@dimen/et_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/et_textSize"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_last_name"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_last_name"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_first_name">

        <com.example.pcwares.utils.pcwaresedittext
            android:id="@+id/et_last_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="@dimen/et_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/et_textSize"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_email"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/et_hint_email_id"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_last_name">

            <com.example.pcwares.utils.pcwaresedittext
                android:id="@+id/et_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="@dimen/et_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/et_textSize"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_password"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/et_hint_password"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_email">

            <com.example.pcwares.utils.pcwaresedittext
                android:id="@+id/et_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="@dimen/et_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/et_textSize"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_confirm_password"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/et_hint_confirm_password"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_password">

            <com.example.pcwares.utils.pcwaresedittext
                android:id="@+id/et_confirm_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="@dimen/et_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/et_textSize"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_terms_and_cond"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_confirm_password">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb_terms_and_cond"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:checked="false" />

            <com.example.pcwares.utils.pcwarestextview
                android:id="@+id/tv_terms_and_cond"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/txt_terms_condition_marginStart"
                android:text="@string/terms_and_cond"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_terms_and_condition_textSize" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.example.pcwares.utils.pcwaresbutton
            android:id="@+id/btn_register"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_bkg"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/btn_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/btn_padding"
            android:text="@string/btn_lbl_register"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_textSize"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_terms_and_cond" />
        
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_register">


            <com.example.pcwares.utils.pcwarestextview
                android:id="@+id/tv_already_have_acc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/clickable_text_view_padding"
                android:text="@string/have_account"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/lbl_text_view_textSize"/>



            <com.example.pcwares.utils.pcwarestextviewbold
                android:id="@+id/tv_login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="@dimen/clickable_text_view_padding"
                android:text="@string/login"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/lbl_text_view_textSize"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Additional image that shows the design [https://imgur.com/a/Ed6oo3m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Eus.png)

Comment: It\`s because of \`com.example.pcwares.utils.pcwaresedittext\`. You don`t use normal EditText class. Please, share com.example.pcwares.utils.pcwaresedittext Class too.

Answer (score 0):

`TextInputLayout` will work good if you use `TextInputEditText` as inside element, we dont see your custom view `pcwaresedittext` implementation.

Please, check: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputEditText

Also my recomendation is to not use custom views if possible, if you need to adjust look of element, use [Styles](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes)